# PHP passing in or'd parameters (bitmask) into a function

Tags: php, function, logical-operators, bitmask

I have a function in php:

```
function renden(array $additional_css_files = array(), $load_js = true, $load_keen = false, $allow_robots = false, $generate_csrf = true) {

}
```

It is becoming really nasty to specific all the optional parameters each time. I'd like to do the following trick using `or'd` flags (bitmask) as a single function parameter.

```
define("LOAD_JS", 1);
define("NO_LOAD_JS", 0);
define("LOAD_KEEN", 1);
define("NO_LOAD_KEEN", 0);
define("ALLOW_ROBOTS", 1);
define("NO_ALLOW_ROBOTS, 0);
define("GENERATE_CSRF", 1);
define("NO_GENERATE_CSRF", 0);


function render(array("foo"), LOAD_JS | NO_LOAD_KEEN | NO_ALLOW_ROBOTS | GENERATE_CSRF) {

}
```

See (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and the paramter `options`. How do I code this logic inside the function?

Comment: Why not pass an array instead? `array('load_js' => true, ...)`?

Comment: a bitmask is a nice dense handy way of representing a bunch of boolean values, not that the performance hit of the (bloated) array would really matter in most settings. One question is why is it a pain to pass all the optional parameters, if they are optional? If you often have to set just one of them that's late in the list, then I could see that. Anyway, extracting the values is easy.. answer coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your define's to bitmasks:

```
// using binary literal notation requires PHP 5.4
define("LOAD_JS", 0b00000001);
define("LOAD_KEEN", 0b00000010);
define("ALLOW_ROBOTS", 0b00000100);
define("GENERATE_CSRF", 0b00001000);
```

Call your function as follows:

```
$flags = LOAD_JS | LOAD_KEEN | ALLOW_ROBOTS | GENERATE_CSRF;
render(array("foo"), $flags);
```

Inside your functions, extract the flags as follows:

```
function renden(array $additional_css_files = array(), $flags = 0b00001001);
$load_js = $flags & LOAD_JS;
$load_keen = $flags & LOADKEEN;
// ...etc
```

Comment: Great, awesome response. If I don't want to load, i.e. lets say default is `true` and I want to pass `false`, do I need `NO_LOAD_JS` or do I simply use `^LOAD_JS | LOAD_KEEN | ALLOW_ROBOTS | GENERATE_CSRF`

Comment: if you call render(array("foo"), LOAD_JS | LOAD_KEEN), for example, you are passing binary 0b00000011 which means ALLOW_ROBOTS and GENERATE_CSRF will be turned off. You could define("DEFAULT", 0b00001001) and then pass (DEFAULT | LOAD_KEEN) & ~LOADJS, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I prepend a parameter with `~` does it negate it?

Comment: So ~ inverts the bits of a parameter, then you have to logically AND with that to turn OFF the bit you don't want. Therefore ($someParams & ~LOAD_KEEN) turns off the LOAD_KEEN bit.